# How to convert UTM coordinates to lat and long in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, data-conversion, utm

I am trying to run a species distribution model and need to create background points to run my logistic regression model. I have just created 500 randomPoints but they are in UTM coordinates and I need lat and long. Is there a way to convert them to lat and long in R? If so, can you share the code with me? I am fairly new to R. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

If you need long/lat you should probably generate the random points using that coordinate reference system. But otherwise you can do something like the below.

I first generate an example set of coordinates (`points`)

```
 set.seed(1)
 x <- runif(10, -10000, 10000)   
 y <- runif(10, -10000, 10000)   
 points <- cbind(x, y)
```

Now, assuming you know the [coordinate reference system](https://rspatial.org/terra/spatial/6-crs.html) (CRS) of your points, you can create a spatial object and assign that known CRS. In my example, the points are in the `UTM, zone 10, datum=WGS84` projection.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(points, crs="+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84  +units=m")
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 10, 0  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : -8764.275, 8893.505, -6468.865, 9838.122  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Now we can transform these to another CRS, for example to `longitude/latitude`

```
y <- project(v, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
y
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 10, 0  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : -127.5673, -127.4091, -0.05834327, 0.08873723  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

And you can extract the coordinates like this

```
lonlat <- geom(y)[, c("x", "y")]
head(lonlat, 3)
#             x             y
#[1,] -127.5308 -0.0530354276
#[2,] -127.5117 -0.0583432750
#[3,] -127.4757  0.0337371933
```

You can of course also do the inverse

```
back <- project(y, "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m")
```

The same thing can be done with the `sf` package, or with the old `sp` package. With `sp`, create a `SpatialPoints` object and use `spTransform`.

```
library(sp)
sputm <- SpatialPoints(points, proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84")) 
spgeo <- spTransform(sputm, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
lnlt <- coordinates(spgeo)
```

I used UTM zone 10 in the example. But note that there are 60 UTM zones and you have to pick one. Each covers a strip of (360/60=) 6 degrees. You should not use UTM if your data spans a lot of longitude or crosses UTM zones. For a longitude between [-180, 180) You can compute the zone you need like this

```
utm_zone <- function(longitude) { trunc((180 + longitude) / 6) + 1 }

longs <- c(-122,-119, -118)
utm_zone(min(longs))
# [1] 10
utm_zone(max(longs))
# [1] 11

utm_zone(max(longs))
```

Or have a look at a map like [this one](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm)

A point of confusion with UTM in the use of "false northings" for locations in the Southern hemisphere, to avoid negative coordinates. This is done by adding 10,000,000 to the y coordinates, as illustrated below using the `+south` element.

```
s <- vect(cbind(174, -44), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
geom(project(s, "+proj=utm +zone=59"))[, c("x", "y")]
#       x          y 
#740526.3 -4876249.1 

geom(project(s, "+proj=utm +south +zone=59"))[, c("x", "y")]
#       x         y 
#740526.3 5123750.9
```

Also note that I use the "PROJ4" notation to define the CRS. That works fine if the datum used (a datum is a model of the shape of the earth's surface) is WGS84 or NAD83. If that is not the case you would need to use an "EPSG" code or a "WKT2" description of your CRS.

Comment: Thanks RobertH, those codes worked. As I am still so new to R, I would now need to convert my new long and lat Spatial Points object back into points so I can plot the long and lat points onto a raster layer in R. Any suggestions?

Comment: A two-column matrix or data.frame

Comment: You should emphasize more strongly in your answer that conversion of UTM to latitude/longitude depends on the UTM zone.  See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67466059/how-to-convert-utm-coordinates-to-lat-and-long-in-r-special-case-africa

Comment: rgdal is no longer in CRAN